# four-order filter bandwidth and the two-order fileter bandwidth is same?

Tags: filter

I have a two-order bandpass filter, the fc = 10k, bandwidth = 2k. Is the bandwidth changed, if I use this to make a four-order bandpass filter ? if No, why the image

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by \$f_c\$?

Comment: Also, what is the source of your table?

Comment: *fc* would be the center frequency, and the value should say 10k*Hz*. And the bandwidth  should say 2k*Hz*.

Answer (score 1):

Your question describes two different cases:

1.) Answer to your first question: Of course, you can design a second-order bandpass as well as a 4th-order bandpass - both with a center frequency of 10kHz and a bandwidth of BW=2kHz. In both cases, the filter quality factor is Q=10/5=2. However, the attenuation properties of the 4th-order filter outside the passband are much better (slope of -40dB/dec instead of -20dB/dec). If the 4th-order filter consists of two 2nd-order sections, both stages are different.

2.) The information content given in the table is quite different: Here you assume that IDENTICAL 2nd-order bandpass sections are cascaded. In this case, of course - as outlined by Photon`s answer - the bandwidth will be reduced for increasing order (more sections).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a two-order bandpass filter, the fc = 10k, bandwidth = 2k. Is the bandwidth changed,

Yes, the bandwidth is changed.

Normally we say the bandwidth of a circuit is where the transmission coefficient has fallen by 3 dB from its value in the center of the passband.

If you cascade two low pass filters with 3 dB loss at some frequency \$f_c\$, the combination will have roughly 6 dB loss at that frequency. So the new bandwidth must be lower than the bandwidth of a single filter.

In the real world, though, the input impedance of the second filter can interact with the output impedance of the first one and make the transfer function of the cascaded filters not as simple as simply multiplying the transfer functions of the two filters. So you really can't generally predict the response of the cascade without knowing what the individual circuits actually are.

Your table probably applies to some specific situation like "two identical one-pole RC filters", or "two identical LC filters". It doesn't apply in all situations where you cascade two low-pass filters with the same cut-off frequency.